# Find a matching cell value in a range and paste cell value if no match is found

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum, match

I am trying to loop through a range titled `mineral` and find a matching cell within a separate list titled `compList` only if a certain range of cells contains a numeric value. If no match is found, then the cell (a string) is copied and pasted into the next available row within compList along with the adjacent cells (numbers). If a match is found, then only the adjacent cells would be added to the existing cells.

This is what I managed to do thus far, it would paste the cell value and adjacent cells as expected, but it would continue to paste these cells even if it already exists in compList. I was not able to create a code to add those values to an existing match since I was trying to figure out this issue.

If you can, please add a brief comment line so I can learn!

Thanks in advance.

```
        
        Dim wsMC As Worksheet
        Dim emptyRow As Long
        Dim mineral, cell, compList As Range, i
        
        
        Set wsMC = Sheets("Mining Calculator")
        Set mineral = Range("B10:B29")
        Set compList = Range("I11:I30")
        emptyRow = wsMC.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   
        If Application.CountA(wsMC.Range("D10:D29")) = 0 Then                     ' Checks if "D" column contains any value
            MsgBox ("Nothing to Add")                                             ' If 'D' column is empty (equals 0) then nothing happens, otherwise go to else
            
            Else
            For Each cell In mineral                                              'For each cell located in 'mineral' range
                If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0 Then GoTo skip                     'If cells 2 columns from 'cell' is empty (equals 0) then skip, otherwise
                
                If Not StrComp("cell", "complist", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then        'Check if 'cell' value already exists within range 'compList' if not then
                        Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = cell.Value                        'Copy 'cell' value to new row in 'compList'
                        Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value          'Copy adjacent cell values from 'cell' to corresponding match in 'compList'
                        Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value          'Copy adjacent cell values from 'cell' to corresponding match in 'compList'
                        Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value          'Copy adjacent cell values from 'cell' to corresponding match in 'compList'
                        emptyRow = emptyRow + 1                                   'Add 1 to emptyRow to avoid replacing last cell value in 'compList'
                        
                    
                        Else                                                      'If 'cell' exists in 'compList' only add adjacent cells to the matching row
                        MsgBox ("it already exists")
                        Exit For
                End If
                
skip:
            Next cell
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does *then only the adjacent cells would be added* mean? Do you have numbers so they will be added or do you have strings to be concatenated (in columns `I:L`)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 The adjacent cells are all ```numbers```. The only string is the ```cell``` variable. I'll clarify that in the original post as well.

Comment: So, if there is a match, copy adjacent cells from match in `compList` and paste next to the comparison value in `mineral` list? A sort of synchronization?

Comment: @bugdrown The other way around. If the cell within the ```mineral``` list is matched with a cell within the ```compList```, then I would like to have the adjacent cells to be added to the existing cells within ```compList``` for the matching cell.

So for example: If a cell in A1:A10 does not exist in column Z, then copy that cell (i.e. A1)  into the next available row in column W along with the adjacent cells (B1,C1,D1) into column X,Y,Z. 

If A1 had already existed within column W, then only add those adjacent cells (B1,C1,D1) into the values that had already existed for A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If Exists Then Sum-up Else New Entry

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMinerals()
    
    ' s - Source (read from) ('Mineral')
    ' d - Destination (written to) ('CompList')
    
    Const scOffset As Long = 2 ' from column 'B' to column 'D'
    
    Dim scOffsets As Variant: scOffsets = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3)
    Dim dcOffsets As Variant: dcOffsets = VBA.Array(2, 1, 3)
    Dim oUpper As Long: oUpper = UBound(scOffsets)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mining Calculator")
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("B10:B" & slRow)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range("I11:I" & dlRow)
    Dim dnCell As Range ' Destination Next Cell
    Set dnCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Dim sCell As Range ' Source Cell
    Dim sValue As Variant ' Source Value
    Dim diCell As Range ' Destination Indexed Cell ('n'-th cell of 'drg')
    Dim dIndex As Variant ' Destination Index ('n')
    Dim o As Long ' Offset Counter
    
    If Application.CountA(srg.Offset(, scOffset)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to Add"
    Else
        For Each sCell In srg.Cells
            If sCell.Offset(, scOffset).Value <> 0 Then
                ' Get the row of the match: if no match, then error.
                dIndex = Application.Match(sCell.Value, drg, 0)
                If IsError(dIndex) Then ' source not found in destination
                    dnCell.Value = sCell.Value
                    For o = 0 To oUpper
                        sValue = sCell.Offset(, scOffsets(o))
                        ' Write new values.
                        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
                            dnCell.Offset(, dcOffsets(o)).Value = sValue
                        End If
                    Next o
                    Set dnCell = dnCell.Offset(1) ' next row
                    Set drg = drg.Resize(drg.Rows.Count + 1) ' include new
                Else ' source found in destination
                    Set diCell = drg.Cells(dIndex)
                    For o = 0 To oUpper
                        sValue = sCell.Offset(, scOffsets(o))
                        ' Add new to old values (sum-up).
                        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
                            diCell.Offset(, dcOffsets(o)).Value _
                                = diCell.Offset(, dcOffsets(o)).Value _
                                + sValue
                        End If
                    Next o
                End If
            End If
        Next sCell
    End If
            
End Sub
```

Comment: It's doing what I want it to, thanks. However, there's a minor issue with it. The source range is from ```B10:B29``` on the last row of that range, ```B30```, I have "total" as well as the first row in the destination range (```I10```). When I run this code, it would be adding the cell as expected, but would also be adding another cell in the destination labeled "total". How can I prevent it from adding "total?" Thanks.
Also, the first cell from the offset is a ```number```, the second is a ```percentage```, and third is ```dollar value```. Its currently all being inputted as a dollar value

Comment: Delete `Dim slRow As Long: slRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` and set the range with: `Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("B10:B29")`.